# Spring Boot/YAML: How to read a map of Strings to Lists?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a property that looks like:

```
@Value(...)
Map<String, List<String>> classToMethods;
```

I want to populate this map via my `application.yml` in a Spring Boot application via the `@Value("...")` annotation. Some sample values are:

```
"java.lang.Double" => ["parseDouble", "toString"]
"java.lang.String" => ["toUpperCase"]
```

How do I represent this in my `application.yml` file? Also, I would like to put placeholder for environmentally injected values from our deployment tool. So for example, I currently have:

```
some:
   property: ${ENV_VALUE:default_value_if_no_env}
```

Basically, this is the syntax I use for injecting values for the specific environment(value for `ENV_VALUE` varies for each environment). I am looking for a way to format the YML map such that this kind of environment replacements are also possible.

Alternative I am thinking of is just creating a String and manually parsing it during constructor injection but would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Have you tried to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to read a map from your .yml config?